# Get facebook friend list using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in AngularJS . I was trying out some code to get a user's Facebook friends list using AngularJS and I found some code here [AngularJS@1.0.1 with Facebook](http://plnkr.co/edit/0GRLdWPJOzGFY14irxLT?p=preview)

In my `index.html` file:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app="funwithfb">
      <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>FB With Angular</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      </head>

      <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="user.connected">
          Hello {{user.first_name}}!
        </div>

        <div class="ng-cloak" ng-hide="user.connected">
          One moment please...
        </div>

        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          FB.init({
            appId      : '272951952842742',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.0',
          });
        </script>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

In my `app.js` file:

```
 var app=angular.module('funwithfb',[]);

  app.controller('MainController',function($scope,Facebook){
    $scope.user=Facebook.getUser(FB);
    console.log($scope.user);
  });
  app.service('Facebook', function($q, $rootScope) {

    // resolving or rejecting a promise from a third-party
    // API such as Facebook must be
    // performed within $apply so that watchers get
    // notified of the change
    resolve = function(errval, retval, deferred) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        if (errval) {
          deferred.reject(errval);
        } else {
            console.log(retval);
          retval.connected = true;
          console.log(retval);
          deferred.resolve(retval);
        }
      });
    }

    return {
      getUser: function(FB) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              resolve(null, response, deferred);
            });
          } else if (response.status == 'not_authorized') {
            FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  resolve(null, response, deferred);
                });
              } else {
                resolve(response.error, null, deferred);
              }
            });
          } 
        });
        promise = deferred.promise;
        promise.connected = false;
        return promise;
      }
    }; 
  });
```

My question is --

1. Although Facebook response is connected, this code **always return user.connected as false** . what's wrong in this code?
2. How deferred serving asynchronous operation for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine actually. All you need to do is to add "http://plnkr.co/" to App Domain of your app registered at Facebook.

Comment: I was looking for some web version not mobile . is there any link you can provide for web ?

Comment: @ChinmoyMaity I updated my answer. Your code is working fine. Just follow my answer. I already tested it. Good luck.

Comment: great,its working . I was trying the same process in localhost and also I changed in facebook app setting accordingly but i'm not getting the result . Any idea ?

Comment: How about trying to leave it blank or put as "localhost" or "http://localhost:port_number/your_app"?

Comment: @ChinmoyMaity Go to `Advanced settings` then input the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` with your localhost url (http:// localhost:port#). See https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/issues/376

Comment: I've tried this but same problem . I'll try it once again . Anyhow you answers helps a lot . Awesome ..